# AJAX Script Load - Proper Order

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a few questions on some behavior I am seeing with my AJAX POST.

I was having issues with using getScript to load 3 .js files in the POST success code. I am seeing on a browser refresh (to test changes) that sometimes the datatable loads (doesn't error out on not a function) and other times it does.

Why does my datatable load work half the time? As I never load datables.js I would expect this to fail every single time. Am I wrong in assuming that javascript loaded in the main page is not available to the AJAX loaded content?

I have tried running async and it doesn't seem to help. I have tried nesting the datatables.js script inside the getScript for bootstrap.js which works, but there is a flicker of the HTML table before the datatable load and it looks really cheesy. When the datatable init is outside the getScript, it doesn't flicker, but as mentioned before, it only works intermittently.

Here is the code:

```
success: function (result) {
// successful request; do something with the data

$.getScript('js/jquery-2.2.4.js');

$.getScript("js/bootstrap.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(textStatus); // Success
    console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
    if (jqxhr.status == 200) {
            //load tooltips (well.. popover)
            $(".itemToolTip").popover({
                trigger: 'hover',
            })

        // required so we can have popups when pagination occurs

            var table = $('#tblItems').DataTable({
                drawCallback: function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
                }
            });
    }
    console.log("Load was performed.");
});

    $('#divTable').html(result);
}
```

Comment: every script and its variables which are loaded through a script tag before this file in your html will be useable in the later included files. So no need for getScript actually.

Comment: If I don't load scripts in the AJAX, nothing that uses the files I am using the getScript for work. I thought this was just how it worked? Am I completely offbase from everything I have read that talks about loaded js not being available to elements loaded with AJAX?

Comment: I still do not get why you are loading them in there. Why load jquery again if you have just issued an AJAX call via jquery. You can use for example jquery in there.

Comment: As I said before, perhaps I misunderstand how AJAX loaded files interact with any JS loaded BEFORE the AJAX called content. So if I have a function that requires jquery called from inside the loaded page, it won't work, it will error out because it can't find the function. If someone could give me a definitive explanation on how previously loaded js works with new AJAX content, it might clear things up.